How to disable android studio code box showing on scroll
https://i.sstatic.net/65Jg9j5B.jpg
How can I disable this feature of android studio in It's editor. I'm beginner in using android studio and this feature of android studio is getting on my nerves. I searched all across android studio setting and couldn't find solution to disable it.
I don't want that box appear when I scroll down in code.
I've tried unchecking Show Code Lens for Context Info in Editor > General > Code Folding but box still appears.

As already noted on the Staging Ground post: This question is similar to: Android Studio creates this kind of overlay on top of everything else showing part of the code. How to disable?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
